Power BI: Automatically set "Between" Data Slicer to Current Data
when opening my report user-confusion may arise from the fact that a date slicer is not automatically extended to the current date of data available.
My question therefore is:
Does anyone know a solution on how to achieve that the end-date selected in the slicer is automatically set upon refresh to the current date?
Between filter in PBI
I explicitly wrote "Between" slicer as I am aware of the excellent solutions for automatically selecting the "Today" Option when having a list of values, where using a text-based solution is feasible, which can however not be combined with the between-function of a slicer field.
In this sense, interested readers may be referred to
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaJ10ilXp6Y
I found another forum thread where somebody also asked about the above mentioned possibility but never got an answer (https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/setting-date-slicer-to-last-refresh-date-by-default/23348/4), which is why I suppose this is an unsettled issue among the PBI community and hope for some explicit answers here.

you can create a measure
Measure = if(max('Table'[Date])<=today(),1)

and add that measure to the filter visual, select measure is 1. Then the end date will be today automatically.

